# need help in start with GCD one method - many calls

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

i want to learn GCD on my own app-project and i've got problem with it. i think is easy but i don't know how solve it. so i've got 2 methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.fe.effect.load", NULL);

__block UIImage *th;

dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
    th = [self doThumbWithImage:thumbnail andTag:1];
    UIButton *btn1 = [self buttonWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100) andBackgroundImage:th andSelector:@selector(doEffect:) andTag:1];
    [self.view addSubview:btn1];
});


dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
    th = [self doThumbWithImage:thumbnail andTag:2];
    UIButton *btn2 = [self buttonWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 100) andBackgroundImage:th andSelector:@selector(doEffect:) andTag:2];
    [self.view addSubview:btn2];
});

}
```

and 2 method:

```
-(UIImage *)doThumbWithImage:(UIImage *)_img andTag:(int)_tag {

ImageProcessing *ip = [[ImageProcessing alloc] initWithImage:_img andTag:_tag];
[ip doImageProcessing];
_img = ip.image;
ip = nil;    

return _img;
```

}

And in `doThumbWithImage:andTag:` i've got `ImageProcessing` class where i do something with my `thumbnail` object.

when i use `dispatch_sync`, time for this operation is the same as without GCD. When i use `dispatch_async`, i can't see thumbanils of buttons. I know something is wrong, but i don't know what.

How can i repair this?

thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to do the addSubview in the main thread.  You can nest the dispatch_async calls to handle that.

Comment: thanks! it's working, but why addSubview must be in main queue? can you explain me that?

Comment: Anything that updates or touches display (UIViews) needs to be done in the main queue.  My understanding is that much of the UI is not thread safe (or not thread safe for us mortals).